# String index out of bounds exception java

Tags: java, exception, substring

I am getting the following error when calling a function from within my class:
java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: -1
Although I used a system prints to see the inputs I am passing in the substring() function and everything seems to be right. The function isContained() returns a boolean value defining whether the substring passed as a parameter is in a list of words. My code is:

```
for(int i=0; i<=size; i++)
    for(int j=i+1; j<=size; j++)
        if(isContained(str.substring(i,j-i)))
            System.out.println(str.substring(i,j-i));
```

where size is the size of the string (str) I am passing in the function

Comment: i think the problem is when i=0 and j = size.

Comment: did u even tried to debug it

Comment: I don't think the problem is there fly. The error comes up for i=1..

Comment: Try to Debug your program. Put printouts(i could read that you already tried that), so use a Debugger. If you are using Eclipse IDE it has a built in Debugger.

Comment: I am afraid I already did

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are calling `str.substring(i, j-i)` which means `substring(beginIndex, endIndex)`, not `substring(beginIndex, lengthOfNewString)`.

One of assumption of this method is that `endIndex` is greater or equal `beginIndex`, if not length of new index will be negative and its value will be thrown in `StringIndexOutOfBoundsException`.

Maybe you should change your method do something like `str.substring(i, j)`?

---

Also if `size` is length of your `str` then

```
for (int i = 0; i <= size; i++)
```

should probably be

```
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
```

Comment: You are right... I thought the method was accepting (index, length)

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to change the looping condition which is the problem here. You are looping one more iteration when you do `<=size` and the index starts from `i=0`. You can change this

```
for(int i=0; i<=size; i++)
```

to

```
for(int i=0; i<size; i++)
```

and also take care about the inner loop condition.

Comment: Why negative voting here?

Answer (score 0):

`IndexOutOfBoundsException` -- if the beginIndex is negative, or endIndex is larger than the length of this String object, or beginIndex is larger than endIndex.

Actually, your right edge of your substring function may be lower than the left one. For example, when `i=(size-1)` and `j=size`, you are going to compute `substring(size-1, 1)`. This is the cause of you error.