# StringIndexOutOfBounds in Java

Tags: java, string, operators, character

I have two exact copies of code here, except one has '<' in the for loops while the other has '<='. Could someone please explain why I get the index out of bounds exception when I use '<=', but then it works fine with '<'

Error code:

```
for(int i = 0; i <= str.length(); i++) {
      int count = 0;
      char currentChar = str.charAt(i);
      for(int j = 0; j <= str.length(); j++) {
        if (currentChar == str.charAt(j) ) {
          count++;
```

Working code:

```
for(int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
      int count = 0;
      char currentChar = str.charAt(i);
      for(int j = 0; j < str.length(); j++) {
        if (currentChar == str.charAt(j) ) {
          count++;
```

If I don't use <= how will it compare the last character in the string?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because come on, just step through your code and look at the values of each variable. You know what the problem is, don't make us do the thinking for you.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20162145/string-index-out-of-bounds-exception-java

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Valid `String` indexes in Java, just like the indexes in any array, go from zero to length minus one. So clearly if you set up your condition to go up to `i <= str.length()`, you'll get outside the string.

Remember that a `String` on the inside is nothing more than a `char[]`, and again: the valid indexes go from `0` to `length-1`. This is a convention, followed by many other programming languages that decided to start counting from zero instead of one.

Answer (score 0):

Because you cannot access `str.chatAt(str.length())` without throwing a exception.

`a < b` means "`a` is less than `b`" and it will be `false` when `a` equals to `b`.

`a <= b` means "`a` is less than *or equals to* `b`" and it will be `true` when `a` equals to `b`.

To compare the last character in the string, write some code to do so, compile and run.

```
bool res = currentChar == str.charAt(str.length() - 1); // assuming str has string with one character or more
```

Answer (score 0):

`str.length()` returns the number of characters in the `String`. So `"String".length()` returns `6`.

Now, when using indices, you start with zero. so `"String".charAt(0)` returns `'S'`. `"String".charAt(6)` gives you a `StringIndexOutOfBoundsException` because the last character in `"String"` is at index `5`.

Answer (score 0):

String indexes begin at 0. str.length() returns how many elements are in your array. if you have a string

"dog"
"dog".length() = 3,
'd':0, 'o':1, 'g':2.

Since your for loop initializes i to 0, the working loop goes through indexes 0-2, which is 3 values, while the non-working one goes 0-3, and references a null, and str.charAt(3) does not exist.